# webhost php: can't manage to relocate to my index page

Tags: php, localhost, hosting

i am trying to host my website made on php,

i am trying to use hostinger, my index page is located in

root/public/index.php

so i created an htaccess file where i've put this
DirectoryIndex public/index.php

this index page is a router with all my path

but when i try the link i get an HTTP 500 error

can't manage to find how to solve this problem

in visual studio to start my project i had to cd into my public folder then start the localhost server everything works fine,

but i can't manage to get the same result when hosting this project

here is my index file code i don't think it is the problem but i don't know maybe.

```php
<?php

use App\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Core\Application;
use App\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Controllers\SiteController;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__) . '/');
$dotenv->load();

$config = [
    'smtp' =>
    [
    'host' => $_ENV['SMTP_HOST'],
    'port' => $_ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
    'username' => $_ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    'password' => $_ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    'from' => $_ENV['SMTP_FROM'],
    'name' => $_ENV['SMTP_FROM_NAME'],
    ],
    'userClass' => \App\Model\User::class,
    'db' => [
        'dsn' => $_ENV['DB_DSN'],
        'user' => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
        'password' => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],

    ]
];

$app = new Application(dirname(__DIR__) , $config);

$app->router->get("/" , [\App\Controllers\BlogController::class , 'index']);
$app->router->post("/" , [\App\Controllers\BlogController::class , 'index']);
$app->router->get("/page/{page:\d+}" , [\App\Controllers\BlogController::class , 'index']);

$app->router->get('/blog-page/{id:\d+}' , [\App\Controllers\BlogController::class, 'articlePage']);

$app->router->get('/contact' , [SiteController::class , 'contact']);
$app->router->post('/contact' , [SiteController::class, 'contact']);
```

[and this is how my hostinger folder look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnk3V.png)

can't fully post the code because 'it looks like a spam' but it's just a bunch of path

thank you

*******************EDIT******************

So i managed to show my page it was my bad, i didn't enable errors so i couldn't see the problem was in my pdo, fixed it,

but here i have a problem
my index page is shown like this
http:[www.mywebsite.com/](http://www.mywebsite.com/) , it work fine.
But when i try to put let's imagine
http::[www.mywebsite.com/store](http://www.mywebsite.com/store)
everything after / will throw me an error 404 ,
i don't know it was working in my localhost, now it doesn't want

if someone have a solution i would be glad.

Comment: I know nothing about hostinger but I'd guess that `/public` is the actual folder files get served from. Place all of your project  files in this folder. Just a guess though

Comment: yes public got the index file, my goal is to not let the user be able to access files within the same file as my index, and my project is made in some way i can't change it now or all directories will be broken ,

basically i'm just supposed to launch my project from index page but it's not working even with htaccess, yet it's working in local server

Comment: There should be an error within the .htaccess file. Is your index file located under the document root? If yes, please paste the code of .htaccess or verify the error by renaming the .htaccess file and see if your site is accessible or not. 
Alos, let me know the exact path where your index file is located so I can provide the .htaccess rules accordingly.